# My onCreateView is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have this piece of code for instantiating my Android app:

onCreate:

```
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        //Adding all the tabs!
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Servers").setIndicator("Servers"),ServerTab.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Shoutbox").setIndicator("Shoutbox"), ShoutBoxTab.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Leader\nboards").setIndicator("Leader\nboards"), LeaderBoardsTab.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("About").setIndicator("About"), AboutTab.class, null);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

When this is called, the onCreateView of the second tab (ShoutBox) is called four times. Resulting in a lot more loading time then needed. During the loading I didn't touch my phone or changed its state(Rotation etc). Why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more info or more code, unfortunately this is not enough.

Comment: Well this it the only piece of code where the ShoutBox tab is created!